# getfilesystemencoding() differs if called via configuration management

Tags: python, python-2.7, environment-variables

If a script gets called via configuration management (in my case salt-stack), it fails. If called via shell it works.

I used the tool [dumpenv](https://github.com/guettli/dumpenv/) to differences of the environments.

The getfilesystemencoding() is different:

[image: dumpenv-getfilesystemencoding-differs]

The environment variables look not much different:

[image: dumpenv-os-environment-variables]

What causes the getfilesystemencoding() to be wrong on the right side?

Python version: 2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [getfilesystemencoding()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) documentation, points to the [nl_langinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nl_langinfo.3.html) documentation, suggesting that `LC_CTYPE` is used to determine the encoding.

So, if your environment had `LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"` you would probably have `UTF-8` as the `getfilesystemencoding()` output, instead of `ANSI_X3.4-1968` (better known as US-ASCII).

Answer (score 3):

Python chose filesystemencoding by LC_CTYPE.  LC_CTYPE="C" caused ASCII filesystem encoding.

FYI, Python 3.7 implemented [PEP 538](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0538/) and [PEP 540](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0540/).  It uses UTF-8 by default even when LC_CTYPE="C".